# Create/Update/Delete and Add to Outlook 365 Contact List

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

When I connect to my Office 365 outlook account and go to *People*

[image]

I have the ability to create: Contacts | Contact List | Group

[image]

I manually create a Contact List (MySuperList) to which I add two contacts:

[image]

In turn, I now have the ability to send an email to that particular Contact List (MySuperList):

[image]

According to the [Microsoft Graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contact), it appears I have the ability to view contacts, create contacts, view the list of contact folders and create a contact folder

[image]

But nowhere do I have the ability to create/view a *Contact List* or even Add to that *Contact List*. Something like:

[image]

Does anyone know if Microsoft Graph plans to support this (or not)?

More importantly, does anyone know if there is a way to programmatically create/update/delete and add stuff to a contact list using some sort of REST API or Client Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing contact lists is not supported in the Microsoft Graph. There's a UserVoice feature request for this at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/8560324-office365-api-allow-to-create-get-and-update-con and I encourage you to upvote it. We use this feedback as a way to help prioritize feature development and to communicate progress back to developers.

Comment: You are correct sir, it appears I need to use Exchange Web Services EWS to achieve my task. Here is a post where I share the final result if anyone cares. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303588/update-office365-personal-contacts